# Como seleccionar cualquier parte del input date y me aparezca el calendario

Tags: html, bootstrap

quisiera saber la forma de que me aparezca el calendario al momento de seleccionar el fondo blanco de el input date, normalmente lo hago así:

```
 <input type="date" value="" class="form-control">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Lo que dices esa es la función predeterminada del `input type date`. No te está funcionado o cual es el inconveniente?

Comment: Si funciona el input, lo malo es que tengo que seleccionar el icono de el calendario para que aparezca, y lo que quiero es que me aparezca cuando seleccione cualquier parte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya ha pasado  tiempo desde que realizaste la pregunta, pero dejo la forma que lo solucione yo por si alguien más lo necesita. Solo agregue las siguientes clases.

```
.input-container input {
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 0;
    padding: .75rem;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    background: transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
}
```

Aquí lo encontré https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334960/how-to-show-calendar-popup-when-inputtype-date-is-on-focus

Answer (score 0):

Justo estoy buscando esa respuesta, sin tener que usar un tipo de framework. si llegaste a solucionarlo compartelo

Comment: Hola Noel, esta es la zona de respuestas, por favor, borra este comentario para evitar recibir votos negativos.

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/374912)